# Is it possible to do LDAP authentication with eDirectory from Java application?

Tags: java, ldap, single-sign-on, novell

I have to implement LDAP authentication with eDirectory in Java application. I guess some of you have tried this solution. Can you share your ideas and if possible sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java and eDirectory used to have problems back in the day as you can see here http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=547273  and here https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22236  Hopefully now things are much better.  The recent release of classes is about a year ago, http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/LDAP_Classes_for_Java

Answer (score 0):

Simple LDAP authentication with Username and Password is quite straightforward as the accepted answer references from the Developer page at Novell.

Complexity arises when you want to use some other method, like X.509 certs, Smart Cards, biometrics and so on.